# How to wait until iframe refresh is done before executing function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am refreshing an iframe on my page when someone clicks on an image with this code:

```
 $("img").click(function() {
      $('#space iframe').attr('src', function(i, val){ return val; });

      openBox();
 });
```

But I only want to execute openBox() function after the iframe is done refreshing.

How can I achieve something like that?

Comment: Try using the `.load` method http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I shortened my code for demonstration just. But openBox() is a function I made. And I want to only execute that function after the iframe is done refreshing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this isn't exactly your problem, here is how you listen for an load event on an `iFrame`.

HTML

```
<iframe id="frame"></iframe>
<button id="loadFrame">load frame</button>
```

JS

```
$("#loadFrame").click(function () {
    $("#frame").attr("src", "http://www.google.com");
    $("#frame").on("load", function () {
        alert("ad");
    });    
 });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7RL35/4/

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery:

```
$('#frameId').on('load', function() {
  //code to execute after frame loaded
});
```

Using vanilla JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('frameId').addEventListener('load', function() {
  //code to execute after frame loaded
});
```